# Iterate over dataframe columns by index and step 2

Tags: python, dataframe

For a dataframe like this

```
      M1_x      M1_y         M2_x         M2_y
0        2  0.861626            2     0.980591
1        4  0.685437            4     0.647706
2        8  0.495346            8     0.303102
3       16  0.327949           16     0.133477
```

I would like to plot two lines, M1 and M2 where each has X and Y points. By iterating the columns like this:

```
n = df_scales.shape[1]-1   // Number of columns is 4, we iterate 0,1 and 2,3
for index in n:
    x = df_scales.iloc[:, index]
    y = df_scales.iloc[:, index+1]
    plt.plot( x, y, marker = 'o')
    plt.show()
```

But I get this error:

```
    for index in n:

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How can I fix that? Or a better method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
for idx in range(0,len(df_scales.columns),2):
    x = df_scales.iloc[:, idx]
    y = df_scales.iloc[:, idx+1]
    plt.plot(x, y, marker = 'o')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, after retrieve the number of columns, iterate over it with step=2

```
n = len(df_scales.columns)
for index in range(0, n, 2):
    # your code
```

Comment: `df_scales.columns` is of type **Index** not **int** so will cause an error when passed to range().

Comment: Thank you, it was a mistack.. I edited by adding a `len()`